# How To Create Multi-Project Template Using Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Visual Studio provides many inbuilt templates for creating a project. Project template will allow a developer to create new projects based on your exported project.
how can I create a new project template for solution with multiple projects?

Comment: It is documented https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-multi-project-templates?view=vs-2019